# How to stretch the table row in Android?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have three dynamically created table row in my app. First and second row have only one text view respectively. And their table row have 3 text view.

When the second row's text view have long length text means, third row gets stretched. How to solve this?

[In this screen shot, third row is stretched extra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIXZj.png)

Comment: How about posing a screen shot and the layout code.  From your description, it's a bit difficult to visualize your problem.

Comment: i have added a screenshot now. please check it

Comment: Minimal typo/readibility, anyways the question seems to me okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

span text view of 1 and 2nd row

`TableRow.LayoutParams txtViewParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); txtViewParams.span = 3; project.setLayoutParams(txtViewParams);`

i hope this works

Comment: it does not work. it showa null pointer exception. int android.widget.TableRow$LayoutParams.span' on a null object reference. but i create the textView dynamically. here is my code. plz check it ' project = new TextView(SlideMenu.this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams txtViewParams=(TableRow.LayoutParams)project.getLayoutParams();
        txtViewParams.span = 3;
        project.setLayoutParams(txtViewParams);'

Comment: what is bLp here??

Comment: TableRow.LayoutParams txtViewParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        txtViewParams.span = 3;
        project.setLayoutParams(txtViewParams);